# Weird string in VIM on ubuntu not showing in excel on windows

Tags: excel, vim

I am working on a research project. And I have a window laptop and what I do is I make a .csv file of my data and I upload it to a Ubuntu server.

Now, on my windows when you open .csv file, some of the column data is shown jargon like in attached "hash photo.png" but when you expand column it shows proper data as shown in "column_expanded.png".

But, my friend when he opens the same .csv file using VIM on Ubuntu server he sees some jargon data.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel shows `#####` when the full value does not fit the cell; expanding it fixes that. Vim shows the raw CSV data, it has no notion of cell [widths]. Raw data can mean that a different date/time format is used than what Excel displays (it typically converts to your user's locale, configured in Control Panel).

You didn't show (excerpts of) the original CSV file, so I can only guess about the discrepancies.